# Given a file, can I check if an identical file exists in the history of a git repo?

Tags: git

Given a git repository with a file `foo.c`, and an arbitrary file, can I check if the given file ever existed with identical contents as `foo.c` in the repository?

That is, given some copy of a file `foo.c` I want to check if such (byte-wise identical) `foo.c` ever existed in the repository.

Comment: Are you looking only for an identical copy with the same name, or would you be interested in finding an identical copy with a different name?

Comment: @KeithThompson - both. The common use case is the name is the same so if that admits a simpler or faster solution than the general case I want to know. I am also interested in the general case of identical files with different names, but with a lower priority.

Comment: That information should be in your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I think it's fine how how it is. I think it is clear enough I'm looking for a file with the same name, and if someone wants to include a more general solution that works for *any* filename, I'm OK with that too. I don't think I need to be explicit about this constraint because it's not really a constraint.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be:

```
git cat-file -t $(git hash-object path/to/foo.c)`  # Assuming bash syntax...
```

This would print `blob` if any file byte-identical to `foo.c` has been committed to the repo (regardless of file path/name),
and `fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info` if it does not exist in the repo.

It computes the sha-1 hash of your input file `path/to/foo.c`, then it queries the type of the git-object identified by that hash, which will yield an error message if the file does not exist in the git object database.

Drawback is that it just answers the question whether the file exists in the repo.
It doesn't tell you the path of the matching file, or which commit/commits that contain the matching file.

Answer (score 1):

Find the file with `git log --all -- foo.c` or perhaps `git rev-list --all | xargs -I '{}' git ls-tree --full-tree -r '{}' | grep 'foo.c'`. Then you could compare hashes with `git ls-files -s foo.c` for the one in the git repo and `git hash-object foo.c` for the one in your file system, just to ensure it's the same file.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the file" here?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Located it in your git repo (if it exists). That's what you asked isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't understand what you mean by "find the file with `git log`". It is not obvious to me how git log finds the file, I have to find it first and pass the path to git log, right?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.  `git log --raw` shows the old and new sha's at every changed path, maybe the simplest output to paw through would be from

```
git log --raw --no-abbrev --all -m --pretty=format:%H
```

and hunt for your sha in that.

If "some copy of a file `foo.c`" means you don't necessarily want to add that `foo.c` to the repo, you can get shas for arbitrary content with e.g. `git hash-object foo.c`, otherwise `git rev-parse` can hunt up any existing id.

So something like

```
git log --raw --no-abbrev --all -m --pretty=format:%H \
| awk 'NF==1 {commit=$1} $4==thehash{print commit,$0}' thehash=`git hash-object foo.c`
```